# Payum Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, symfony, payum

i am using the payumBundle for my payment set ups but i keep getting this error:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

These are my classes that i am using

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="payum_tokenized_details")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TokenizedDetails extends BaseTokenizedDetails
{

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="payum_paypal_express_checkout_payment_details")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PaypalExpressPaymentDetails extends PaymentDetails
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


}
```

i have tried to search but i can't seem to find a solution, normally this is because of the primary keys, but those are all set up correctly

Comment: The error you see means that the database rejects data because it violates the definition of the data-structure. You most likely did provide the wrong ID somewhere (0). Normally 0 is not a fitting value for a PRIMARY KEY (PK). In your case that value is already inside the database, which shows that you have a more fundamental underlying problem. Not only the duplicate but also that it is already in. Restore your last working backup on another test-system and try to re-create the faulty 0 database entry.

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation, know i know where i have to look for.

Answer (score 0):

The TokenizedDetails entity must not have id field because there is token one (which is unique ) and already had been mapped.

See how its defined in sandbox: https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/master/src/Acme/PaymentBundle/Entity/TokenizedDetails.php

And the mapping: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping/TokenizedDetails.orm.xml

Pay attention to token field its defined as id.

Comment: since 0.6.0 TokenizedDetails was deprecated and removed in 0.7. So now you have to use Token model. previous `token` field was renamed to `hash`.